# How to define Spring Data Repository scope to Prototype?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring data jpa & hibernate for data access along with Spring boot. All the repository beans are singleton by default. I want to define the scope of all my repositories to `Prototype`. How can I do that?

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {
    List<Customer> findByLastName(String lastName);
}
```

**Edit 1**

The problem is related to domain object being shared in 2 different transactions which is causing my code to fail. I thought it is happening because repository beans are singleton. That's the reason I asked the question. Here is the detailed explanation of the scenario.

I have 2 entities `User` and `UserSkill`. `User` has 1-* relationship with `UserSkills` with lazy loading enabled on `UserSkill` relation.

In a `UserAggregationService`, I first make a call to fetch an individual user skill by id `123` which belongs to user with id `1`.

```
public class UserAggregationService {
  public List<Object> getAggregatedResults() {
    resultList.add(userSkillService.getUserSkill(123));
    //Throws Null Pointer Exception. See below for more details.
    resultList.add(userService.get(1));
  }
}
```

Implementation of UserSkillService method looks like

```
@Override
public UserSkillDTO getUserSkill(String id) {
    UserSkill userSkill = userSkillService.get(id);

    //Skills set to null avoid recursive DTO mapping. Dozer mapper is used 
    //for mapping.
    userSkill.getUser().setSkills(null);
    UserSkillDTO result = mapper.map(userSkill, UserSkillDTO.class);

    return result;
}
```

In the call of user aggregation service, I call UserService to fetch userDetails. UserService code looks like

```
@Override
public UserDTO getById(String id) {
    User user = userService.getByGuid(id);

    List<UserSkillDTO> userSkillList = Lists.newArrayList();
    //user.getSkills throws null pointer exception.
    for (UserSkill uSkill : user.getSkills()) {
       //Code emitted
    }
    ....
    //code removed for conciseness 

    return userDTO;
}
```

UserSkillService method implementation

```
public class UserSkillService {
  @Override
  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
  public UserSkill get(String guid) throws PostNotFoundException {
    UserSkill skill = userSkillRepository.findByGuid(guid);
    if (skill == null) {
        throw new SkillNotFoundException(guid);
    }
    return skill;
  }
}
```

UserService method implementation:

```
public class UserService {
  @Override
  @Transactional(readOnly = true)
  public User getByGuid(String guid) throws UserNotFoundException {
    User user = userRepo.findByGuid(guid);
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UserNotFoundException(guid);
    }

    return user;
  }
}
```

Spring boot auto configuration is used to instantiate entity manager factory and transaction manager. In the configuration file spring.jpa.* keys are used to connect to the database.

If I comment the below line of code, then I do not get the exception. I am unable to understand why change in the domain object is being affecting the object fetch in a different transaction.

```
userSkill.getUser().setSkills(null);
```

Please suggest If I have missed something.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @OliverGierke, I have updated the question with more context. Please suggest if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @OliverGierke Can you help and share your thoughts?